# How to improve my validation of input and output

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have the function `insert`, and it checks given POST-values and inserts them into the database. I first check if the request quantity is available in the database. If successful, I insert the the request into the databse. If not, it should display an error message.

My checks work for taking out quantities, but not for adding quantities.
How could I solve this problem, or improve the validation?

The code:

```
<?php

require_once('./database/connect_bd.php');

function insert(){

    $dbc = connection();

    $returnn = array();
$errors = array();
    $admin;
    $product;
    $record;
    $amount;

if($_POST['product'] == ""){
        $errors[] = 'The product field is required!';
    }else{
        $product = $_POST['product'];
    }
   if($_POST['admin'] == ""){
        $errors[] = 'The admin field is required!';
    }else{
        $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    }
if($_POST['record'] == ""){
        $errors[] = 'The field record is required';
    }else{
        $record = $_POST['record'];
    }
 if(empty($_POST['amount'])){
        $errors[] = 'The field amount is required';
    }else{
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    }
if(empty($erros)){
      $query = "select SUM(ret.amount) AS amount,
            ret.product_name,
            ret.id_product
            from(SELECT 
            SUM(p.amount) AS AMOUNT, 
                p.record_type, 
                p.id_product, 
                c.name AS name_product, 
                c.image
                FROM stock p JOIN administrator u 
                           ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin 
                           JOIN register_products c 
                           ON c.id_product = p.id_product
                           WHERE p.record_type = 'input'

                           GROUP BY                 
                           p.record_type, 
                           p.id_product, 
                           c.name, 
                           c.image 
                           UNION
                           SELECT 
                           -SUM(p.amount) AS AMOUNT, 
                           p.record_type, 
                           p.id_product, 
                           c.name AS name_product, 
                           c.imagem
                           FROM stock p JOIN administrator u 
                           ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin 
                           JOIN register_products c 
                           ON c.id_product = p.id_product
                           WHERE p.record_type = 'output'

                           GROUP BY                 
                           p.record_type, 
                           p.id_product, 
                           c.name, 
                           c.image)ret
                           WHERE ret.id_product = $product
                           group by ret.name_product,
                           ret.id_product";

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $amount_db = $row['amount'];

if($amount_db >= $amount || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){


        $query = "INSERT INTO stock(id_stock, amount, record_type, id_admin, id_product, dt_drive) VALUES (NULL, $amount,'$record', '$admin' ,'$product',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

  $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

 if($result){
            $returnn[] = 'successfully completed registration';

        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Some error occured while registering the stock!';
        }
 }else{

        //stock error
        echo"<script>alert('Value Exceeds amount in stock'); history.go(-1)</script>";
    }


    }else{

        $return = $errors;

    }

    return $returnn;
}?>
```

Comment: You validate nothing here. Also, you should get rid of `@` operator in the first place (and add proper error handling)

Comment: The better way to do this is with an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent). If you don't use something like that you'll spend weeks painfully and badly implementing the same thing anyway.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Sorry guys, I started programming a short time, and still do not know the proper way to write the codes.

Comment: Apart from you checking problem I'm a bit worried about the SQL statement you run. It might work for small amounts off entries, but with a lot of products and stock entries it probably will become very slow.

Comment: Nothing wrong with just getting started. The problem with this approach is you quickly end up re-inventing the wheel. Since you want validations, you should look at the various ORMs out there and find one that you like, then learn it well. They will save you a ton of time and hassle and make you a much more effective programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. What I think you did wrong is a general check, if the amount given in the post-request is greater than the amount available in the database. But this is only try, if your $_POST['record'] is "output". You must not check this, if your $_POST['record'] is "input".

So to rewrite this one line of code:

```
if(($amount_db >= $amount && $_POST['record'] == 'ouput' ) || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
```

But I have to say, that your code needs a complete rework done. Not just that one line. See the given comments above.